# How to get id of clicked div jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have been trying to get the id of a clicked `div` of **same classes** but with **different IDs**. I tried everything I know.
Here is one code I tried **(in this one, the `.click function()` does not work** .. edit: meaning it does not seem to run the code when clicked at all!):-

```
$(".u_search").click(function() {
    var attr_u_search = $(this).attr('id');
    var dataString = '&u_search=' + $(".u_search").attr('id');
    alert(dataString);

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/script/profile.php',
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
          $('#ui_profile').show();
          $('#ui_profile').html(data);
          location.hash = 'profile' + 'id=' + dataString;
          $(".searchbox").val('');
          $("#usr_suggest").hide();

    }
  });
});
```

PHP:-

```
echo "<tr id='" . $id . "' class='u_search' height='40px'><td width='40px'><img class='avatar' src='$avater' /></td><td>" . $fname_ . " " . $lname_ . "</td></tr>";
}}
```

---

Here is another combination of codes I tried (**error in this one**: suppose I have 5 `divs`, and even if I clicked the 2nd div or the 3rd div, it only captures the id of the first `div` [`div` 1] and not the clicked `div`. I want to be able to **capture the id of the clicked `div`**.):-

```
$(".u_search").click(function() {
    var attr_u_search = $(".u_search").attr('id');
    var dataString = '&u_search=' + $(".u_search").attr('id');
    alert(dataString);

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/script/profile.php',
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
          $('#ui_profile').show();
          $('#ui_profile').html(data);
          location.hash = 'profile' + 'id=' + dataString;
          $(".searchbox").val('');
          $("#usr_suggest").hide();

    }
  });
});
```

PHP:-

```
echo "<tr id='" . $id . "' class='u_search' height='40px' onclick='javascript:op_prof(1)'><td width='40px'><img class='avatar' src='$avater' /></td><td>" . $fname_ . " " . $lname_ . "</td></tr>";
}}
```

**edit: when I use the first code (the one with `.click function()`) the code does not seem to run at all! .. I am using jquery library version 1.9.1**

Comment: which version of jquery are you using ?

Comment: `$(".u_search").attr('id')` will [always return the ID of the *first* element](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) with that class. Does `$(this).attr('id')` (i.e. your `attr_u_search`) not give you what you want?

Comment: jquery version 1.9.1 (provided by google)

Comment: Ok see my answer, I changed how you call the click()

Comment: Please post your HTML code too. THe problem doesn't seem to be with the jQuery code.

Comment: using this is better than using $("some_sector")

Comment: It is within the jquery code @Mysteryos

Comment: Run a debugger or add some debugging alert statements. Make sure it's getting to this block of code. Also, alert/debug out the value of $(this) once you're inside the .click function.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function change

```
$('.u_search').attr('id')
```

To

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

The quotes are important, but this is not inside quotes ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think it's :  `$(this).attr('id')`
You need use $(this) to have the object that clicked..

```
var attr_u_search = $(this).attr('id');
var dataString = '&u_search=' + attr_u_search; // it's better !
```

Comment: the read the question carefully before answering ... he already used your answer

Comment: On beginning, he had $('u_search') ...And when he try to get the good id, he don't use $(this) !

Comment: in every `.click(...)` change $('u_search') by `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
$(".u_search").click(function() {...
```

your callback function has now an object called `this`. You can use it to get the actual object you've clicked. So in this case, if you want to get the ID of the clicked object, simply do this:

```
var the_id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: seems that you have not read the question ... he is using `var attr_u_search = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: You've edited your code. You've previously used the `search()` function!

Comment: You don't find it weird that three people answered the question as if he wasn't using `this` already? Also, if you make an edit quickly enough, the question won't indicate it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function, you can reference to the active jquery object by using $(this)

```
$(".u_search").click(function() {
 ...
 //get ID of button being clicked upon
//Jquery Solution
 $(this).attr('id');

//Or Javascript
  this.id;
 ...
}
```

Comment: The question has been edited, that's why a few people have provided this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("div").on("click",function(){
     var id = this.id; //returns id
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var attr_u_search = $(this).attr('id');
var dataString = '&u_search=' + $(".u_search").attr('id');
```

You're selecting every u_search div again to build your datastring, instead of using the already fetched id:

```
var attr_u_search = $(this).attr('id');
var dataString = '&u_search=' + attr_u_search;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('body').on('click', '.u_search', function() {
  var attr_u_search = $(this).attr('id');
  var dataString = '&u_search=' + attr_u_search;
  alert(dataString);
  // REST OF CODE
});
```

(Tested and working, if it still does not work, the issue might be somewhere else)

Comment: check that you include JQuery before the code and that the code comes after the html

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').delegate('.u_search', 'click', function() {
    var attr_u_search = $(this).attr('id');
    var dataString = '&u_search=' + attr_u_search;
    alert(dataString);
});
```

Comment: Try to alert value of attr_u_search

Comment: the first codes dont work at all. the second one shows the id of the first div as alert...