# How to capture id of clicked div - jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am posting this questions due to the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103610/how-to-get-id-of-clicked-div-jquery) being so long (It might create confusion if I cut parts up in it). I made the question more simple in this post :).

jQuery code:-

```
function op_prof(id) {
    var attr_u_search = $(".u_search").attr('id');
    var dataString = 'u_search=' + attr_u_search;
    alert(dataString);

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/script/profile.php',
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
          $('#ui_profile').show();
          $('#ui_profile').html(data);
          location.hash = 'profile' + 'id=' + dataString;
          $(".searchbox").val('');
          $("#usr_suggest").hide();

    }
  });
};
```

PHP:-

```
echo "<tr id='" . $id . "' class='u_search' height='40px' onclick='javascript:op_prof(1)'><td width='40px'><img class='avatar' src='$avater' /></td><td>" . $fname_ . " " . $lname_ . "</td></tr>";
}}
```

I am having trouble retrieving the `ID` of each `div` (each one has a unique `ID`). It seems that the jQuery captures the `ID` of the `div` on top (the first `div`) instead of capturing the `ID`s of all the `divs`.

Screen shots:-

http://prntscr.com/118dhv

http://prntscr.com/118dus

P.S: I am 100% sure that there is an error in the jQuery :-> prntscr.com/118eb5

Comment: you can do this by `$('div').click(function(){alert($(this).attr('id'));})`

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify the `on-click` attribute of `tr`

From this:

```
onclick='javascript:op_prof(1)
```

To this:

```
onclick='javascript:op_prof(this)'
```

And the js to this:

```
function op_prof(obj) {
    var attr_u_search = obj.id;
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery already, here's a full jQuery solution:

```
$("tr.u_search").on("click", function() {
    var attr_u_search = $(this).attr('id');
    var dataString = 'u_search=' + attr_u_search;
    alert(dataString);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/script/profile.php',
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ui_profile').show();
            // $('#ui_profile').html(data);
            location.hash = 'profile' + 'id=' + dataString;
            $(".searchbox").val('');
            $("#usr_suggest").hide();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Is first param of 'ob_prof' always = 1?

```
javascript:op_prof(1)
```

Comment: For future reference: this isn't an answer, it's a comment, once you've gained >50 reputation you'll be able to leave comments to other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The attr() method sets or returns attributes and values of the selected elements.

When this method is used to return the attribute value, it returns the value of the FIRST matched element.

use $.each()

api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/